# level-db golang implementation writing over existing values?

Tags: go, leveldb

I am trying to use the leveldb-g implementation and having some issues.

Here is my implementaation (based on another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12647378/leveldb-go-example-docs)

```
package propertyData

import (
    "code.google.com/p/leveldb-go/leveldb/db"
    "code.google.com/p/leveldb-go/leveldb/table"
    "log"
    "runtime"
)

const (
    DBFILE = "./admin.db"
)

var DBFS = db.DefaultFileSystem

func AddDataToProperty(property, value string) {
    Connection, e := DBFS.Create(DBFILE)
    Check(e)
    w := table.NewWriter(Connection, nil)
    defer w.Close()

    e = w.Set([]byte(property), []byte(value), nil)
}

func GetDataFromProperty(property string) string {

    v := findOne([]byte(property))

    return string(v)
}

func findOne(k []byte) []byte {
    Connection, e := DBFS.Open(DBFILE)
    Check(e)
    r := table.NewReader(Connection, nil)
    v1, err := r.Get([]byte(k), nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("An error occurred finding one", err.Error())
    }

    return v1

}

func Check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        _, file, line, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
        log.Fatalf("Bad Happened: %s, %s", file, line)
    }
}
```

and a test:

```
package propertyData

import (
    "com.levelsbeyond/admin/propertyData"
    "log"
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func TestAddProperty(t *testing.T) {
    os.RemoveAll("./admin.db")

    propertyData.AddDataToProperty("test.property", "one")
    propertyData.AddDataToProperty("test.property", "two")
    propertyData.AddDataToProperty("test.property", "three")

    propertyValue := propertyData.GetDataFromProperty("test.property")
    log.Println(propertyValue)

    propertyData.AddDataToProperty("test.different", "four")
    propertyValue = propertyData.GetDataFromProperty("test.different")
    log.Println(propertyValue)

    propertyValue = propertyData.GetDataFromProperty("test.property")
    log.Println(propertyValue)

}
```

Which outputs:

```
=== RUN TestAddProperty
2013/09/16 10:47:50 three
2013/09/16 10:47:50 four
2013/09/16 10:47:50 
--- PASS: TestAddProperty (0.00 seconds)
```

It's like writing the second property ("property.different") Overwrites the values I already have in there. I'm sure I'm doing something dumb, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I added some error handling in the findOne function (thanks @miltonb) and I actually am getting an error there, though I'm not sure what to make of it:

```
=== RUN TestAddProperty
2013/09/16 15:36:34 three
2013/09/16 15:36:34 four
2013/09/16 15:36:34 An error occurred finding one%!(EXTRA string=leveldb/db: not found)
exit status 1
FAIL    command-line-arguments  0.018s
```

Comment: First thing I would do is find out if an error is being produced from your findOne function.  Change to `v1, err := r.Get([]byte(k), nil)  if err != nil { // error handling`

Comment: The strange error is actually from your logging try with %v: `log.Fatalf("An error occurred finding one %v", err.Error())`.  Secondly the actual error from leveldb 'not found exit status 1' indicates the Get has not retrieved the value which explains the blank entry in your TestAddProperty

Comment: I just noticed there is no closing of db connections, just a thought, as I am not sure what the leveldb expectations are.

Comment: The compiler complains when I try to call Close() on the Connection object. Looking at some of their tests a bit, and they're using memfs instead of DBFS, here is the [table test](https://code.google.com/p/leveldb-go/source/browse/leveldb/table/table_test.go). I suppose I will try to ape that test until it works, or maybe I should just use sqlite instead. I'm trying to use an embedded database for a very light service that is monitoring and describing a very heavy service, so minimal dependencies is ideal..

Comment: I accidentally stumbled upon levigo which looks to be an alternate implementation with what looks to be very similar API: http://godoc.org/github.com/jmhodges/levigo

Answer (score 2):

Change to another implementation of leveldb with what looks to be better documentation such as levidb http://godoc.org/github.com/jmhodges/levigo.

Comment: I personally prefer some very pragmatic features instead of ORMs or other high abstractions. It is completely enough to have a [mapper tool](https://github.com/kisielk/sqlstruct) to map rows into models and to [test it](https://github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock) conveniently. This leaves you all the features database provides, no wtf factors or complexity.